# check if function is defined on child class only

Tags: php

```
 <?php 
    class controller
    {
     public  function view()
      {
        echo "this is controller->view";
      }

}
class home extends controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    echo "this is home->index";
  }
  function page()
   { 
    echo "this is home-> page";
   }

}


$obj= new home;

$method="index";// set to view or page
if(method_exists($obj,$method))
{
 $obj->{$method}();
}

?>
```

my problem :
If we set $method to view, the view() from base controller class will be called.
i want to check if $method exist on home class only
(don't want to check if  the function   is defined in base class )
 any idea how this can be implimented?

Comment: It kind of goes against the idea of inheritance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define base class function as private.

Change

```
public  function view()
      {
        echo "this is controller->view";
      }
```

to

```
private  function view()
      {
        echo "this is controller->view";
      }
```

It will be work...

**EDIT**

```
function parent_method_exists($object,$method)
{
    foreach(class_parents($object) as $parent)
    {
        if(method_exists($parent,$method))
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(!(method_exists($obj,$method) && parent_method_exists($obj,$method)))
{
    $obj->{$method}();
}
```

This will working perfectly in your case...

Also refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307938/method-exists-in-parent-class-php)

Comment: thanks , but now i cant access the view() from inside home class .  i just want to know if the function is **decleared** inside home . (there is  a situation that i have to use $controller=new controller;
$controller->view(); inside home)

Comment: +1 for the edit. The original answer is no good since you lose the ability to call `view()` on the parent directly.

Comment: Thanks The edit works ,function view() should  be public so it can be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @vignesh's answer, I needed to use `is_callable()` to make it work.

```php
abstract class controller {
   private function view() {
      echo "this is controller->view";
   }
}

class home extends controller {
    public function index() {
        echo "this is home->index";
    }
  
    public function page() { 
        echo "this is home->page";
    }
}

$home_controller = new home;
is_callable([ $home_controller, 'view']); // false
```